# JavaFX Getting TreeView's prefWidth

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, width, treecell

I've been trying to determine a TreeView's preferred width but all I get when I call `getPrefWidth()` is `-1`. Is there a reason for that? For me the preferred width would be the width of the widest cell. That value must be stored somewhere since scrollbars are displayed when the TreeView doesn't have enough space to show all of it's content.

Comment: You're getting the value [`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE) (which basically means the tree view's preferred width is not hard-coded, but is computed from the preferred widths of its skin's child nodes). There's usually no reason to know the preferred width at any given time, but if you really need it try calling `prefWidth(-1)` (or perhaps `prefWidth(prefHeight(-1))`).

Comment: "That value must be stored somewhere": I don't think it is, actually, I think it's computed when needed during a layout pass.

Comment: I tried calling `prefWidth(-1)`. It gave me something but it was not the value I need. Internally the Skin seems to get the width by calling `getWidth()` on `VirtualFlow<TreeCell<T>>`. I tried to access that using reflection but I failed because I am developing in Java 9.

Comment: You could navigate the scene graph using CSS lookups, but imho that will lead to madness... Why do you need this? Perhaps there is another solution entirely to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using a `TreeView` in a `SplitPane`. Right now the SplitPane makes the TreeView as large as possible since no maxWidth has been set. I don't want to set it to any random value because these things can vary so much depending on the monitor you use. The "prefWidth" I've been trying to get is the maxWidth I want to set for the TreeView.

Comment: Doesn't `setMaxWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)`, or `setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)` work? (Also, make sure the other components in the split pane have max widths that allow them to expand.)

Comment: `setMaxWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)` was what it was previously set to. That didn't help. I tried using `setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)`. That was a lot closer but too small. I am using a custom TreeCell. I store all my custom stuff in the `graphic` variable. Maybe that's the problem?